# Java Heap Memory Error for processing large files

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

While processing Large file i am getting Java Heap Memory error. I am developing tool which checks specified regex on each line/sheet from  file. It works fine for below 2mb files but when i process large size files it gives error.

Application uses recursive function to loop on Files and folders.

Please help me with this, because i need to run it on multiple user system.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so before posting your next question here. Questions asking about why code is not working must include the relevant code in the post itself, in the form of an [mcve], must contain a clear description of the problem, and must ask a **specific** question related to that code. You've done none of those things.

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the java heap size by setting Xmx. for example: -Xms256m -Xmx2048m